# Pass Grunt Jade Options to File

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using grunt-contrib-jade and I am wanting to use the pkg.name and pkg.version to build out my css file name. I can't get this to work and hope someone can help me on this. Here is what I have:

Part of jade task in Gruntfile

```
compile: {
    options: {
        data  : {
            app    : '<%= pkg.name %>',
            version: '<%= pkg.version %>',
        },
        pretty: true
    }
```

Then in my jade file I have:

```
link(href='_assets/css/<%= app %>-<%= version %>.css', rel='stylesheet', media='screen')
```

Don't know how to add the data from the compile options from the jade task in Gruntfile.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have not loaded package.json into your Grunt config add the folloing to your grunt file.

```
grunt.initConfig({
   pkg: require("./package.json"),// <---- add this line
   compile: {
       options: {
          data  : {
              app    : '<%= pkg.name %>',
              version: '<%= pkg.version %>',
          },
          pretty: true
       }
  }
});
```

I personally prefer to add it under a meta object like as follows:

```
grunt.initConfig({
   meta{
      pkg: require("./package.json"),// <---- add this line
   },
   compile: {
       options: {
          data  : {
              app    : '<%= meta.pkg.name %>', // <-- notice i added meta
              version: '<%= meta.pkg.version %>',// <-- notice added meta
          },
          pretty: true
       }
  }
});
```

you could also try the following:

```
var pkg = require("./package.json");

grunt.initConfig({
   compile: {
       options: {
          data  : {
              app    : pkg.name, // <-- notice no quotes and no micro templating
              version: pkg.version ,// <-- notice no quotes and no micro templating
          },
          pretty: true
       }
  }
});
```

this aproach is not as dynamic as the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth understanding of how to do this